# Responsive container fluidity

Tags: html, css

I really appreciate your help. I am currently working on a responsive webpage. My layout for it is a bit like apples. I have a big header (slideshow) and placed 3 pictures under it. The slider is already responsive so when i minimize it it is getting smaller. The problem is that the 3 images placed under this slider arent going up. What I mean with it is that they don't go up with the slider so there is a huge gap between them. I think my problem is the absolute position but im not quiet sure how to fix it.

Heres my Code for the menu, slider, pictures:

http://www.mediafire.com/download/z148onn81c1oa4d/Website_Problem.rar

This is a link for all those who cant see the problem in the posted code. I really apreciate your help. LG Lyro

```css
.rslides {
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 75%;
  max-height: 88%;
  top: 0;
  left: 12.5%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  float: left;
  }
.rslides li {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  }
.rslides li:first-child {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  }
.rslides img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  }
#news {
    background-image: url("../bilder/news.png");
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: auto 100%;
    height: 32%;
    width: calc(75%/3);
    position: absolute;
    top: 88%;
    left: 12.5%;
    }
#standort {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 32%;
    width: calc(75%/3);
    position: absolute;
    top: 88%;
    left: 37.5%;
    opacity: 0.85;
    }
#öffnungszeiten {
    background-color: orange;
    height: 32%;
    width: calc(75%/3);
    position: absolute;
    top: 88%;
    left: 62.5%;
    opacity: 0.85;
    }
/* Padding regelt die Größe von Nav und Footer */
#logo{
  position: absolute;
  left: 13%;
  width: 15%;
  height: 15%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
   }
#footer-wrapper {
    background-color: #A4CD6F;
    position:absolute;
    width: 75%;
    top: 121%;
    left: 12.5%;
    font-size: 85%;
    }
nav {
    background-color: #DBDAB7;
    position:absolute;
    width:75%;
    top:0%;
    left:12.5%;
    opacity: 0.85; 
    }
ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }
ul li {
    list-style:none;
    }
ul li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    float:right;
    display:table-cell;  
    font-family: Verdana;
    color: black;
    padding:15px 30px 15px 0;
    }
```

```html
<ul class="rslides">
  <li><img src="bilder/IMG_4819.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="Ein Holzstapel hinter Stroh im Eingangsbereich"></img></li> 
  <li><img src="bilder/Bank.jpg" width="100%" height="75%" alt="Unsere Schöne Bank vor dem Eingangsbereich"></img></li>
  <li><img src="bilder/Kartoffeln.png" width="100" height="100" alt="Ein Mitarbeiten an der Gemüse Theke"></img></li> 
</ul> 

<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact us</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
 
<a href="#"><div id="news"></div></a>
<div id="standort"></div>
<div id="öffnungszeiten"></div>
```

I would love to see some help.

LG

Comment: It's difficult to answer something concise with the code you are providing. For example, in the HTML you provided, what are the little images and what is the big responsive one?
It looks like you shoud make the slider container/s responsive as well. Looks like the slider is getting smaller but some container keeps its height.

Comment: @chimos kk what do you need? I can make the complete website online. I really need to fix that. edit. The images are the images for my slider. They are like the content of the rslides

Comment: And where are "the three pictures under it" in the HTML you provided??

Comment: @chimos the 3 pictures are the containers. I make a background so these are the 3 img (news , standort, and öffnungszeiten). I would really apreciate your help otherwise I have to delete 40h of work and use a template cause I only have 2weeks left for this site + 5 sites of text about the website :C

Comment: @chimos I would just need a Idea how I can achieve to place 3 Containers always like 0.5% or 10px or whatever below another container. That would be cool

Comment: Sorry I I can't reproduce the issue with the code you provided. Would be cool if you show enough code to reproduce the problem or a demo showing it.

Comment: I can say that position absolute looks bad for that purpose, since absolute elements position won't be affected by foreign elements height.

Comment: @chimos Ok. I will upload a .rar with all the files for the website on mediafire. Would be nice if you can have a look there and help me with the problem. Heres the link: http://www.mediafire.com/download/z148onn81c1oa4d/Website_Problem.rar           I will also post a link in the mainpost. LG Lyro

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be fixed using media queries.
The position can be reduced according to the device sizes.

Comment: Ye but the slider doesnt get smaller when the screen is size X it has always 75% of the screen size so when i use media quaries to fix that problem I need to make like 100 that sucks.

Comment: Yes, I think the problem is more about *fluid* than about *responsive*.

Comment: do you need to bring the three pictures up only for mobile.

Comment: I dont know what you exactly mean with only for mobile. The three containers with the pictures are like my main content of my side. I just need them to stick under my Slider when the height of my slider is getting smaller

Comment: then what you can do is, through media queries reduce the top percentage. i did in my local and it works.

Comment: I already thought about it in theorie a nice idea but I dont only have to consider all different combos of the current width and height of the current website.

Comment: I would just need a Idea how I can achieve to place 3 Containers always like 0.5% or 10px or whatever below another container

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see the link you provided. But in your HTML, just keep the things ordered as you want them to appear. The "three images" that you want below the slider should be simply direct below it. And why you position everething absolute? In your CSS the slider and the three images should be relative or static, and not absolute.

**HTML:**

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact us</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>


<ul class="rslides">
  <li><img src="bilder/IMG_4819.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="Ein Holzstapel hinter Stroh im Eingangsbereich"></img></li> 
  <li><img src="bilder/Bank.jpg" width="100%" height="75%" alt="Unsere Schöne Bank vor dem Eingangsbereich"></img></li>
  <li><img src="bilder/Kartoffeln.png" width="100" height="100" alt="Ein Mitarbeiten an der Gemüse Theke"></img></li> 
</ul> 

<a href="#"><div id="news"></div></a>
<div id="standort"></div>
<div id="öffnungszeiten"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.rslides {
    position: relative; /*This changed*/
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 75%;
    max-height: 88%;
    top: 0;
    left: 12.5%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    float: left;
}
#news {
    background-image: url("../bilder/news.png");
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: auto 100%;
    height: 32%;
    width: calc(75%/3);
    /*position: absolute;*/ /*Avoid this*/
    top: 88%;
    left: 12.5%;
}
#standort {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 32%;
    width: calc(75%/3);
    /*position: absolute;*/ /*Avoid this*/
    top: 88%;
    left: 37.5%;
    opacity: 0.85;
}
#öffnungszeiten {
    background-color: orange;
    height: 32%;
    width: calc(75%/3);
    /*position: absolute;*/ /*Avoid this*/
    top: 88%;
    left: 62.5%;
    opacity: 0.85;
}
```

Comment: Hmm ok. But when I change them to relative they arent quite there where they have to be. The boxes are smaller etc. So I have to place all 3 containers relative to the slider? Is that right?. btw the link is a mediafire link in the main post.

Comment: @lyro: not relative to the slider. The default CSS position is _static_. If they were all static, they would be one under another, as you need. It looks like you are abusing of absolute positioning. Chances are that you should use other layout techniques and minify the use of absolute when possible. Absolute positioning is used in some rare cases normally. I can't help further without a demo and don't want to download and debug your files. I think you should provide an accessible demo. Best regards